# minus from previous row and then from new row

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I want to do the following:
Starting balance is 1000.
Next day purchases are 500.
the day after purchases are 200.

I want to display:

```
date        Transaction  balance
----------  ---------  -------
09/20/2016       1000     1000
09/21/2016       -400     600
09/22/2016       -200     400
09/23/2016       -500     -100
09/24/2016        700     600
```

So query should minus purchases column from balance column to get a new balance.

It is not giving me the correct output.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

---

Thanks alot MathGuy

Comment: Something's wrong with the first row. If the starting balance is 1000, purchases is also 1000, and purchases must be subtracted from balance, why isn't the balance 0 after the first purchase? Also odd that purchases reduce the balance; is that actually a loan balance and "purchases" are in fact payments? Also, is balance allowed to drop below zero?

Comment: I wrote the wrong heading. $1000 is the starting balance and then the rest are transactions (which I wrote under heading "purchases")

Comment: OK, how about can balance drop below zero? Did you see that question?

Comment: Yes. It can drop below zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the balance may drop below zero, or if purchases (in total) are guaranteed not to exceed the initial balance, it's a simple matter of SUBTRACTING a running sum (`sum(purchases) over (order by date1)`) - or perhaps also partition by [whatever] in the "over" clause - from the beginning balance.

You must show a better input table though; I hope that is not how you have it structured, with amounts of 1000 and 500 and 300 in the same column, NOT differentiated by sign (+ for balance, - for initial balance) AND no separate column to show the amount, "balance" or "purchase." The only way to interpret your requirement is that the "date" and "purchases" columns are given, and you want the first amount to be treated as "initial balance" and the others as "purchases", which makes no sense. The problem CAN be solved in that case too, but first please clarify your real situation.

ADDED:

With the further clarification and the updated input data from the OP, the problem is a direct application of the analytic function SUM():

```
select transaction_date, transaction, 
       sum(transaction) over (order by transaction_date) as balance
from   input_table;
```

Note - I didn't use "date" as a column name; "date" can be used as a column name (but only with some effort, since it is a reserved word), but that is a very bad practice. I used "transaction_date" instead.

Comment: Oh, but then you can just use a running sum:  adding to the Answer above.

Comment: Why/how is it not helping? Clearly using the first two columns as "inputs" a query that returns three columns as I have shown in the ADDED section does exactly what you illustrated in the updated table, so if that "is not helping" please explain how your desired output is different from what you showed. Or, first, just test the code I wrote for you and see if it doesn't, actually, help! Good luck either way.

Comment: OK... this makes absolutely no sense. If you are already summing up transaction amounts, why is that column called "transaction"? Show your BASE data, not the result of some solution you have written half of, and which is not working (as you yourself have said). Say: here is the BASE data, and here is what I want to get from it.

Comment: the above query I placed in the question worked - Thanks again!